# Define JPA Entity Graph in a separate file

Tags: java, jpa, annotations, entity, spring-data-jpa

Is it possible to define an Entity Graph for a JPA Entity (the `@NamedEntityGraph` annotation) in a separate file from the Entity definition?

If my project becomes a little complex I have an enormous block of ugly/unreadable code before my entities for these definitions..

Comment: clearly you can define an entity graph programmatically via API, that qualifies as in a "separate file"

Comment: is there no way to use the annotation syntax moving it in another file?

Comment: the JPA spec only requires persistable classes be scanned for annotations.

Comment: you can also define an entity graph in XML mapping file

Comment: @wypieprz can you provide me an example or a reference?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have an entity annotated with @NamedEntityGraph as below:

```java
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "Project.graph"
  attributeNodes = {
    @NamedAttributeNode(value = "deadline"),
    @NamedAttributeNode(value = "employees", subgraph = "Employee.subgraph")},
    ...
  subgraphs = {
    @NamedSubgraph(name = "Employee.subgraph",
      attributeNodes = {
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "salary")}
        ...
  )}
)
public class Project {
    ...
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date deadline;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="project", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Collection<Employee> employees;
    ...
}
```

In persistence.xml add reference to your XML mapping file (let's say orm.xml):

```
...
<mapping-file>META-INF\orm.xml</mapping-file>
...
```

which in respect to the above @NamedEntityGraph may be defined as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">
    ...
    <entity class="com.example.Project">
        <named-entity-graph>
            <named-attribute-node name="deadline" />
            <named-attribute-node name="projects" subgraph="Employee.subgraph" />
            ...
            <subgraph name="Employee.subgraph">
                <named-attribute-node name="salary" />
                ...
            </subgraph>
        </named-entity-graph>
    </entity>
</entity-mappings>
```